# Evaluate object to a boolean

Tags: php, class, object, evaluation

Consider the following:

```
class MyClass
{
  private $var1 = "apple";
  private $var2 = "orange";
}

$obj = new MyClass();

if($obj) { 
  // do this
}
else {
  // do that
}
```

PHP evaluates my object to true because it has member variables. Can this logic be overridden somehow? In other words, can I have control over what an object of my class will evaluate to when treated as a boolean?

Comment: No, as of yet, we can only control it in string casting.

Comment: Why do you need to have that unusual behavior ?

Comment: The best you can achieve are `if( $obj() )` or `if ("$obj")` or `if (count($obj))` in lieu of boolean evaluation.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> PHP evaluates my object to true because it has member variables.

This is incorrect. PHP actually evaluates `$obj` as `true` because it holds an object. It has nothing to do with the contents of the object. You can verify this by removing the members from your class definition, it won't make any difference in which branch of the if/else is chosen.

There is no way of making PHP evaluate a variable as false if it holds a reference to an object. You'd have to assign something "falsy" to the variable, which includes the following values:

```
null
array()
""
false
0
```

See the [Converting to boolean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) from the PHP documentation for a list of all values that are treated as `false` when converted to a boolean.

Comment: True. To clarify for the OP, `$obj` isn't the object. Rather, it is a *reference* to the location of the object, used by PHP to find the point in memory where the actual object begins.

Comment: `"PHP evaluates my object to true because it has member variables." This is incorrect.` Actually, this *was* true in PHP 4, but PHP 5 changed the behaviour to be as you describe.  Not vastly relevant, but historically interesting.

Answer (score 23):

The best you can do is using `__invoke`:

```
class MyObject {

    private $_state;

    public function __construct($state = false) {
        $this->_state = $state;
    }

    public function __invoke() {
        return $this->_state;
    }

}

$true  = new MyObject(true);
$false = new MyObject(false);

var_dump($true());   // true
var_dump($false());  // false
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use small extension for php7: https://github.com/p1ncet/obcast. As you may see from the description, it allows to cast an object to boolean by implementing new internal interface Boolable:

```
$obj = new class implements Boolable {
    public $container = [];
    public function __toBoolean() {
        return count($this->container) > 0;
    }
};

var_dump((bool) $obj);

$obj->container = [1];
var_dump((bool) $obj);
```

output:

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

Comment: Strange why this isn't a built-in function. I'd expect there to be one like this due to the presence of `__toString()` since PHP 5.2

Comment: I would expect a `__toPrimitive()` or `__toValue()` or something like that which would work for any non-object value.

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't.  Unfortunately boolean casting in php is not modifiable, and an object will always return true when converted to a boolean.

Since you clearly have some logic you mean to place in that control statement, why not define a method on your object (say "isValid()" ) that checks the conditions you wish to check, and then replace:

```
if ($obj)
```

with:

```
if ($obj->isValid())
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is what I'll have to do, but I just wanted to simplify coding a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for being late, but I just played with similar task and have made some kind of a hack/workaround. Notice `"$object"` pattern which calls `__toString` method.

```
class tst {
  public $r = true;
  function __toString() { return $this->r ? "1" : "0"; }
}
$object = new tst();
$object->r = true;
echo '<br />1: ';
if ("$object") echo 'true!'; else echo 'false!'; // "$object" becomes "1" == true
//echo "$object" ? 'true!' : 'false!';

$object->r = false;
echo '<br />0: ';
echo "$object" ? 'true!' : 'false!'; // "$object" becomes "0" == false
```

Output:

```
1: true!
0: false!
```

Answer (score -4):

You can do it like that :
(bool) $yourObject

will