# how to create a php class which can be casted to boolean (be truthy or falsy)

Tags: php, class, boolean

I am creating a collection class and would like it to be drop-in-replacement for arrays, which I use currently.

**How to create a class which could be casted to boolean, so the class can be truthy or falsy?**

A simple test shows that an object of empty class is truthy:

```
class boolClass {}
$obj = new boolClass();
var_dump( (bool)$obj);
//prints 
//bool(true)
```

But I need to decide if my class is truthy or falsy. Is there eny way to tell the PHP engine how to cast my class to boolean? Like I could do with __toString()?

Background:

Lets say I write a class like this (it's an example only):

```
class MyCollection implements ArrayAccess, Iterator {
    //...
}
```

I heavily use this patterns currently:

```
$var = array();

if (empty($var)) {
   //array is empty, (or there is no array at all)
   // I do something here
}
```

I would like that to look like:

```
$var = new MyCollection(array());
```

and keep the rest unchanged. But the $var containing MyCollection is always truthy so I would need to all the conditions to:

```
if ($var->isEmpty()) {
    //...
}
```

But this is unacceptable, as my codebase have many megabytes.

Any solution here?

Comment: i think you need a method inside your class which will return the current state of the object if it is truthy or falsy

Comment: there are more answers here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572849/evaluate-object-to-a-boolean/5572929 e.g. a php extension to support this kind of cast https://github.com/p1ncet/obcast

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On this page, the magic methods that you can define for your classes are enumerated.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring

You demonstrate that you already know about `__toString()`.

Unfortunately, there is no magic method listed there that does what you are asking. So, I think for now your only option is to define a method and call that method explicitly.

Answer (score 27):

After much angst, disappointment, and hacking - I believe I have found a solution. The solution doesn't call for any extensions; it can be implemented with a very small amount of PHP boilerplate. However, before implementing this solution yourself, please take note that this is - in fact - a HUGE hack. That being said, here is what I discovered:

Frustrated, I spent some time looking over the [PHP documentation for Booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting). While user-created classes are simply denied the ability to be cast as a boolean, one class - oddly enough - was afforded the capability. The astute reader would notice that this class is none other than the built-in [SimpleXmlElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php). By process of deduction, it seems fair to assume that any subclass of SimpleXmlElement would also inherit its unique boolean-casting capability. While, in theory this approach seems valid, the magic surrounding SimpleXmlElement also takes away from the utility of this approach. To understand why this is, consider this example:

```
class Truthy extends SimpleXmlElement { }
```

Truthy is a subclass of SimpleXmlElement, so we should be able to test if its special boolean-casting property was inherited:

```
$true = new Truthy('<true>1</true>'); // XML with content eval's to TRUE
if ($true) echo 'boolean casting is happening!'; 
$false = new Truthy('<false></false>'); // empty XML eval's to FALSE
if (!$false) echo 'this is totally useful!';
```

Indeed, the boolean-casting property afforded to SimpleXmlElement is inherited by Truthy. However, this syntax is clumsy, and it is highly unlikely that one would get much utility out of this class (at least when compared to using SimpleXmlElement natively). This scenario is where the problems start to come up:

```
$false = new Truthy('<false></false>'); // empty XML eval's to FALSE
$false->reason = 'because I said so'; // some extra info to explain why it's false
if (!$false) echo 'why is this not false anymore?!?';
else echo 'because SimpleXMLElements are magical!';
```

As you can see, trying to set a property on our subclass immediately breaks the utility we get from the inherited boolean-casting. Unfortunately for us, the SimpleXmlElement has another magical feature that breaks our convention. Apparently, when you set a property of a SimpleXmlElement, it modifies the XML! See for yourself:

```
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement('<element></element>');
$xml->test = 'content';
echo $xml->asXML(); // <element><test>content</test></element>
```

Well there goes any utility we would get from subclassing SimpleXmlElement! Thankfully, after much hacking, I found a way to save information into this subclass, without breaking the boolean casting magic: comments!

```
$false = new Truthy('<!-- hello world! --><false></false>');
if (!$false) echo 'Great Scott! It worked!';
```

Progress! We were able to get useful information into this class without breaking boolean-casting! Ok, now all we need to do is clean it up, here is my final implementation:

```
class Truthy extends SimpleXMLElement {

public function data() {

    preg_match("#<!\-\-(.+?)\-\->#", $this->asXML(), $matches);

    if (!$matches) return null;

    return unserialize(html_entity_decode($matches[1]));


}

public static function create($boolean, Serializable $data = null) {
    $xml  = '<!--' . htmlentities(serialize($data)) . "-->";
    $xml .= $boolean ? '<truthy>1</truthy>' : '<truthy/>';
    return new Truthy($xml);
}

}
```

To remove some of the clumsiness, I added a public static factory method. Now we can create a Truthy object without worrying about the implementation details. The factory lets the caller define any arbitrary set of data, as well as a boolean casting. The data method can then be called at a later time to retrieve a read-only copy of this data:

```
$false = Truthy::create(false, array('reason' => 'because I said so!'));
if (!$false) {
   $data = $false->data();
   echo 'The reason this was false was ' . $data['reason'];
}
```

There you have it! A totally hacky (but usable) way to do boolean-casting in user-defined classes. Please don't sue me if you use this in production code and it blows up.

Comment: Hehe, unbelievable! :) Unfortunately for the last round of polishing: if you go as far as adding `Truthy::create` you can as well just return `null` from there (with try/catch) if construction fails. And, since that's the vast majority of cases where we'd check objects as bool (for (un)successful initialization), it's hard to justify the trouble. Still a very interesting hack, cheers!

Comment: We used this hack in our code for a few years, but when it came time to serialize anything using this object, it just did not work. `SimpleXmlElement` would not work properly with `serialize()`. So we now are removing the hack.

Answer (score 6):

You can take a look at the PHP [operator extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/operator) which you can use to overload many operators including == and ===. With this extension, you should be theoretically able to write a class comparable to boolean values like this:

```
if($object == true)
```

Comment: Whoa, never thought it would be possible in php. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

In PHP an object when cast to `bool` always produces `true`. There is no way of changing that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is `__invoke` method which seems close to your intention:

```
class boolClass {
    public function __invoke() {
        return true;
    }
}
$obj = new boolClass();
var_dump( (bool)$obj());
//prints 
//bool(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a code size of "many megabytes" the issue is probably not that your naming scheme is too verbose. I would instead look for duplication and try to abstract code.

OTOH, why is the size of the code a big issue? Try to minimize the code you are including each time php runs. Stray code that isn't used makes no difference. If you *have* to include a lot of code, consider using caching software, such as MMCache.

And to answer your original question, AFAIK there is no way to add type coercion to PHP classes. an instance will always evaluate to true.

Comment: I might have been imprecise. The application I work on is a few years old application which started as not so big CRM system and evolved to full blown ERP system. There are over a hundred of different modules which realize separate business goals. There are many common structures, which at the moment are stored as arrays of objects, and I want to convert them to collections. I have no resources to refactor all the modules to use new Collection class just because I want new technology. I need a backward compatible solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to implement your own method you could hack your way into `__toString`, like this:

```
class foo
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return strval(false);
    }
}

$foo = new foo();

if (strval($foo) == false) // non-strict comparison
{
   echo '$foo is falsy';
}

echo (bool) strval($foo); // false
```

Comment: I still have to change the conditions I use. If I would be force to do that, I would rather use a method to check if my collection is not empty. See my comment for @Adam Bergmark post

Comment: @SWilk: Yeah, however I don't think you can do that without implementing custom methods (even with the PECL operator package). =\