# Is undefined a data-type in php?

Tags: php, types, undefined

Is `undefined` a data-type in php?
Also, how does one check for it (on a variable, is or is not undefined)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "undefined" data type in PHP. You can check for a variable being set with [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), but this cannot distinguish between a variable not being set at all and it having a `null` value:

```
var_dump(isset($noSuchVariable)); // false

$nullVariable = null;
var_dump(isset($nullVariable)); // also false
```

However, there is a trick you can use with [`compact`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) that allows you to determine if a variable has been defined, even if its value is `null`:

```
var_dump(!!compact('noSuchVariable')); // false
var_dump(!!compact('nullVariable')); // true
```

**[Live example](http://ideone.com/fGqjhm)**.

Both `isset` and the `compact` trick also work for multiple variables at once (use a comma-separated list).

You can easily distinguish between a `null` value and total absence when dealing with array keys:

```
$array = array('nullKey' => null);

var_dump(isset($array['nullKey'])); // false
var_dump(array_key_exists($array, 'nullKey')); // true
```

**[Live example](http://ideone.com/bZgihi)**.

When dealing with object properties there is also [`property_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php), which is the equivalent of `array_key_exists` for objects.

Comment: I have variables that are set (return true from isset), but return as `undefined` (from print_r and echo). This behavior seems to conflict with some of what you are saying.

Comment: @ColinBrogan: That's most likely because those variables have the string value `"undefined"`. Why don't you `var_dump()` them and see for yourself?

Comment: Right you are Jon.  The variables came from json, where undefined is a datatype. Then when the json was converted to PHP array, it became a string. Thus begetting my conceptual confusion. Thx!

Comment: @downvoter: Please help me improve this answer by leaving a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, undefined is not a data type in PHP. You check if a variable is set (i.e. previously defined and not `null`) in PHP with [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset):

```
if( isset( $foo)) { 
    echo "Foo = $foo\n";
} else {
    echo "Foo is not set!\n";
}
```

From the docs, `isset()` will:

> Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.

Comment: Your answer to question 2 can't be right. I have variables that were set to undefined (and print to undefined), and when passed through isset(), isset return true.

Comment: @Colin, No, undefined as a string maybe, but there is no undefined variable type in PHP. You're either declaring your own constant (i.e. `define( 'undefined', null);`), or using the string `'undefined'`. Not to mention that everybody in this thread posted the same answer...

Comment: Twas a string. The variable started in json, where it was an innocent and engenuous little undefined data-type, and then, upon conversion to PHP array, it grew to be an imposter in string form.

Answer (score 3):

`NULL` is the implicit value for undefined variables. [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) will not work, as it ignores variables initialized to `=NULL`.

To probe if a variable is really present, you have to use a workaround:

```
if (in_array("varname", array_keys(get_defined_vars()))) {
```

Answer (score 2):

To check if a variable is defined or not you can try this:

```
<?php
if(isset($myvar)){
echo 'your variable is set as' . $myvar;
}else{
echo 'your variable is not set';
}
?>
```

Also as far as I know 'undefined' is not a data-type in PHP.

Comment: You know, `var_dump();` may come in handy instead

Answer (score 1):

There isn't undefined, but there is `null` different yes. But `undefined` is not a valid Data type, all variables need to be defined. By:

```
$Foo = "Test"; 
if (isset($Foo))
{
 echo "Variable Is Defined";
}
else
{
 echo "Variable Is not Defined";
}



if (isset($UndefinedVar))
{
 echo "Variable Is Defined";
}
else
{
echo "Variable Is Not Defined";
}
```

Your Outputs for each statement would be:

> 1) Variable is Defined
>
> 2) Variable Is Not Defined

---

If undefined variables was a valid datatype within PHP or any programming languages, it would take the ability to work with variables, because essentially.. They would already be in use

Answer (score 0):

(might be a bit over the top)

Here are two fairly "simple" ways to mimic your own *undefined* type. With some overhead for a function call it can be available to your code without using the keyword [global](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global).

```
<?php
class undef1{function __toString(){return 'undefined';}}
function undef1(){
    static $C;
    if($C===null){$C = new undef1();}
    return $C;
}

echo 'undef1 in string context : '; var_dump( undef1().'');
echo 'undef1 in boolean context: '; var_dump( !!undef1() );
echo 'undef1 compared to itself: '; var_dump( (undef1() === undef1()) );


class undef2 extends SimpleXMLElement{function __toString(){return 'undefined';}}
function undef2(){
    static $C;
    if($C===null){$C = new undef2('<C/>');}
    return $C;
}

echo 'undef2 in string context : '; var_dump( undef2().'');
echo 'undef2 in boolean context: '; var_dump( !!undef2() );
echo 'undef2 compared to itself: '; var_dump( (undef2() === undef2()) );
?>
```

the output (PHP 5.3.23):

```
undef1 in string context : string(9) "undefined" // :)
undef1 in boolean context: bool(true)            // :(
undef1 compared to itself: bool(true)            // :)

undef2 in string context : string(0) ""    // :( ?
undef2 in boolean context: bool(false)     // :)
undef2 compared to itself: bool(true)      // :)
```

In either case it seems ticky to get the thing to feel like JavaScript.

To get the object to evaluate to boolean false the second solution uses a [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113387/how-to-create-a-php-class-which-can-be-casted-to-boolean-be-truthy-or-falsy) with the way PHP handles *SimpleXMLElement objects*. However that same hack can backfire if some code alters the XML value of your *undef2* object.

Sadly the magic function __*toString()* becomes [ironically](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/6/14/5) useless when extending the SimpleXMLElement class. Maybe there is another function to overload that will return a custom string but I cannot find it. Though maybe an empty string is actually more practical.

There are [PECL operator overloads](http://pecl.php.net/package/operator) that could maybe get the *undef1* class to evaluate to boolean false, but the extension is beta and might not be available to your PHP code.

*Misc notes:*

It seems that an *undefined* type would make a lot of sense for custom classes that implement ArrayAccess, where it is be possible to:

- ignore creation of elements if the *$value* === *undefined*
- return *undefined* if a key or index is not defined

In the example above the class is not restricted to a singleton. You can make it behave that way if you wish:
[Creating the Singleton design pattern in PHP5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203336/creating-the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php5/203359#203359)