# PHP - Wrap the "undefined check" trick in a function?

Tags: php, reference, null, undefined

I need to be able to make a distinction in PHP between variables that are purely undefined, and variables that are null. PHP makes it difficult to do this. The dilemma is explained in the link below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14309841/3163495

In that link, there is a trick to seeing if a variable is truly undefined, or is simply set to NULL:

> ...there is a trick you can use with "compact" that allows you to
>   determine if a variable has been defined, even if its value is null:
>
> ```
> var_dump(!!compact('noSuchVariable')); // false
> var_dump(!!compact('nullVariable')); // true
> ```

The trick works great by itself, but it breaks when you try to wrap it in a function like so:

```
function IsDefined(& $variable){
    return (!!compact('variable'));
}
```

**The above function IsDefined always returns true, no matter what form of undefined variable I pass it.**
Notice the "&" symbol by the $variable argument--I am passing by reference or else PHP will throw an "undefined variable" error.

How can I get the "undefined check" trick mentioned above into a working, reusable function?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If you have to do it so often that you need a function, it seems like there's a problem with your coding.

Comment: Are they always global variables that you need to check? You can test if `isset($GLOBALS[$varname])`

Comment: @Barmar no they will not be global variables, they will be variables that I will attempt to pass by reference into the function IsDefined

Comment: If they're local to the function, why don't you just use another variable that keeps track of whether you've assigned the variable. `$foo_assigned = false; ... $foo = something; $foo_assigned = true;`. Then just test `$foo_assigned`.

Comment: @Barmar The reason I need to be able to do this is so I can check if $_SESSION variable is set, where NULL is an acceptable value. Currently, if I check if it is set with isset($_SESSION["MyVariable"]), it will return FALSE if the variable is NULL, when I need to to return TRUE, since NULL is a value that it was set with.

Comment: Or refactor so that instead of using separate variables, use an associative array. Then you can test whether the key exists in the array.

Comment: Use `array_key_exists("MyVariable", $_SESSION)`

Comment: @Barmar I have tried that, and it works, however that only works with arrays. I need it to work with all variables

Comment: It works for any session variable.

Comment: Why do you need that? [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, you don't need a solution for any variable, just for session variables. Session variables are not real variables, they're elements of an associative array. So you can use the [`array_key_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) function.

```
function sessionVarDefined($varname) {
    return array_key_exists($varname, $_SESSION);
}
```

Then you can write

```
if (sessionVarDefined('MyVariable') {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The comment about session variables was only an example, I need it to work with all types of variables

Comment: Then I'm back to my comment that there's something wrong with the way you're coding this. Why don't you know which variables you've set?

Comment: I can understand it for session variables, since they're set by other scripts, and you don't know what was done before your script ran. But most variables are not so flightly.