# define if statement for object

Tags: php, arrayaccess

Is there a way to define the boolean returned value for an if statement issued on my class instances?
I have a class implementing the array access interface and so on, but even if the wrapped array is empty:

```
if($class)
```

will always return true, since it is an object and does exists.
I'd rather not have to issue everytime an:

```
if(count($class))
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: yep is a duplicate, close please

Answer (score 2):

If I get the point you can implement the [countable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) interface; This requires you define the `count()` method, which let you know (by using it like `count($myArrayAccessInstance)`) if your internal array has items or not o whatever logic you want to define.

```
class MyAy implements ArrayAccess, Countable
{
    private $data;

    public function offsetExists($key)
    {
         # code...
    }

    public function offsetUnset($key)
    {
         # code...
    }

    public function offsetGet($key)
    {
        # code...
    }

    public function offsetSet($key, $value)
    {
        $this->data[$key] = $key;
    }

    public function count()
    {
        return $this->data > 0;
    }
}

$my = new MyAy();

$my['user'] = "Ilpaijin";

if(count($my))
{
    var_dump($my);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are implementing a class, maybe you could have a member which counts the elements in the array? Something like:

```
class MyClass {

    public $numElems = 0;
    private $elems = array();

    ...

    public function add($elem)  {
        $elems[] = $elem;
        $numElems++;
    }

    ...
}
```

And then, do the `if`like if($class->numElems) ...

Comment: But then I have to keep track of the count everytime I modify the wrapped array or use a (slow as hell) magic method to access dinamically that property calculated everytime on the fly. mmmm, I'll keep it in mind anyway :)

Comment: @lpg Then would be better to implement and use count method: `public function count() { return count($elems); }`

Comment: @lpg Why reinvent something that does already exist? http://de1.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible

```
In PHP an object when cast to bool always produces true. There is no way of changing that.
```

Check answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113387/how-to-create-a-php-class-which-can-be-casted-to-boolean-be-truthy-or-falsy)

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to cast an object to a boolean related to a property inside the class because it always will return true. but I think you just need to create a function inside your class that allows you to return the boolean you need like this

```
public function bool()
{
    return (count($this->array)>0);
}
```

when you need to use it, just call the function like this `if ($obj->bool()) { ... }` and another way to make your statements look like what you wanted to do in the begining is to define a class with a really short name, I usually use `_`, and this function should return the boolean you need just like this

```
function _ ($Obj)
{
    return $Obj->bool();
}
```

finally, instead of testing on your class like this if `($class->bool())` which is a bit long, you do it like this

```
if (_($class))
{ /* do something fun */ }
```